# react-native logcat Why keep showing: D/EGL_adreno: eglMakeCurrent?

Tags: android, react-native

I don't know what this log means.

After this log appears, the application becomes very slow. （UI FPS < 40 ）

may I know what is the reason?

```
04-21 23:43:21.306 15554-15570/***.***.*** D/EGL_adreno: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaf434ac0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xaf4394a0)
04-21 23:43:21.317 15554-15570/***.***.*** D/EGL_adreno: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaf434ac0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xaf4394a0)
04-21 23:43:21.856 15554-15570/***.***.*** D/EGL_adreno: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaf434ac0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xaf4394a0)
04-21 23:43:21.867 15554-15570/***.***.*** D/EGL_adreno: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaf434ac0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xaf4394a0)
04-21 23:43:22.404 15554-15570/***.***.*** D/EGL_adreno: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaf434ac0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xaf4394a0)
04-21 23:43:22.412 15554-15570/***.***.*** D/EGL_adreno: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaf434ac0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xaf4394a0)
04-21 23:43:22.957 15554-15570/***.***.*** D/EGL_adreno: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaf434ac0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xaf4394a0)
04-21 23:43:22.965 15554-15570/***.***.*** D/EGL_adreno: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaf434ac0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xaf4394a0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the mobile application internally, the `open gl` library handles draw your UI content. You can safely ignore these logs